# How get value from local variable and object with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
form = $('#<%= params[:board_id] %>');
var $parent = form.closest(".biscuit").eq(0);
```

I want get values for `form` and `$parent`

If I write:

`alert($parent).value();` or `alert(form).value();` I get in the alert `[object Object]`.

How can I get the values for `form` and `$parent`?

Comment: Hi, try to use a JS debugger like FireBug and stop the script execution to check the variables values.

Comment: Depending on the object .val() could not return something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

`alert($parent).value();` or `alert(form).value();`

instead you should write:

`alert( $parent.val() );` or `alert( form.val() )`

What you wrote, alerts the `$parent` jQuery object and then tries to call method `value()` on the result...

Comment: @hyperrjas yeah a form doesn't have a `value`, only input elements like `select` `input` etc do.

Comment: Is not a form is a link. Thank you!